# Failed assertion with automated initialisation of database in Cassandra

Tags: scala, datastax, phantom-dsl

Completely new to Cassandra. Tried to initialize a database in Cassandra using `phantom-dsl`. I received this error message.

```
*** RUN ABORTED ***
  java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: no symbol could be loaded from class com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster in package core with name Cluster and classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@279f2327
  at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.scala$reflect$runtime$JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$$classToScala1(JavaMirrors.scala:1021)
  at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$$anonfun$classToScala$1.apply(JavaMirrors.scala:980)
  at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$$anonfun$classToScala$1.apply(JavaMirrors.scala:980)
  at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$$anonfun$toScala$1.apply(JavaMirrors.scala:97)
  at scala.reflect.runtime.TwoWayCaches$TwoWayCache$$anonfun$toScala$1.apply(TwoWayCaches.scala:39)
  at scala.reflect.runtime.Gil$class.gilSynchronized(Gil.scala:19)
  at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaUniverse.gilSynchronized(JavaUniverse.scala:16)
  at scala.reflect.runtime.TwoWayCaches$TwoWayCache.toScala(TwoWayCaches.scala:34)
  at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.toScala(JavaMirrors.scala:95)
  at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.classToScala(JavaMirrors.scala:980)
```

I am not really sure whether it is an issue with the `Connector` in `phantom-dsl` or the `ClusterBuilder` in `datastax-driver`.

**Connector.scala**

```
package com.neruti.db

import com.neruti.db.models._

import com.websudos.phantom.database.Database
import com.websudos.phantom.connectors.ContactPoints
import com.websudos.phantom.dsl.KeySpaceDef

object Connector {

  val host= Seq("localhost")
  val port = 9160
  val keySpace: String = "nrt_entities"
  //  val inet = InetAddress.getByName

  lazy val connector = ContactPoints(host,port).withClusterBuilder(
    _.withCredentials("cassandra", "cassandra")

  ).keySpace(keySpace)

}
```

**CassandraSpec.scala**

```
package com.neruti.db

import com.neruti.User
import com.neruti.db.models._
import com.neruti.db.databases._
import com.neruti.db.services._
import com.neruti.db.Connector._

import java.util.UUID

import com.datastax.driver.core.ResultSet
import org.scalatest._
import org.scalatest.{BeforeAndAfterAll,FlatSpec,Matchers,ShouldMatchers}
import org.scalatest.concurrent.ScalaFutures
import org.scalamock.scalatest.MockFactory
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global


abstract class BaseCassandraSpec extends FlatSpec
with BeforeAndAfterAll 
with Inspectors
with Matchers
with OptionValues
with ScalaFutures

class CassandraTest extends BaseCassandraSpec
with ProductionDatabase
with UserService
with Connector.connector.Connector{

        val user = User(
          Some("foobar"), 
          Some("foo@foobar.com"), 
          Some(UUID.randomUUID()),
          )


 override protected def beforeAll(): Unit = {
    Await.result(database.userModel.create(user),10.seconds)
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks there may be multiple issues you are looking at:

The latest version of phantom is 2.1.3, I'd strongly recommend using that, especially if you are just starting out. The migration guide is [**here**](https://github.com/outworkers/phantom#200-migration-guide) in case you need it.

The entire reflection mechanism has been replaced in the latest version, so that error should magically go away. With respect to testing and generating objects, I would also look to include `com.outworkers.util.testing`, which is freely available on Maven Central

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  //..,
  "com.outworkers" %% "phantom-dsl" % "2.1.3",
  "com.outworkers" %% "util-testing" % "0.30.1" % Test
)
```

This will offer you automated case class generation:

```
import com.outworkers.util.testing._

val sample = gen[User]
```